# Unable to check registry for Visual C++ 2008 redistributables using WIX Bootsraper

Tags: wix, registry, visual-c++-2008

I am able to check registry for Visual C++ 2010 redistributables using WIX Bootsrapper using below code

util:RegistrySearch  Id="VC2010x86" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86" Variable="CPP2010Redistx86" Value="Installed" Result="value"

But I do not know how I need check registry for Visual C++ 2008 redistributables using WIX Bootsraper.

What will be the key value I need to use for VC++ 2008 instead of  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86" which I uses for VC++ 2010.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to cover the ProductCodes you can search for:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/01/29/9384143.aspx

or use them to look at the uninstall registry key.

or use them as dependencies. To be honest, I usually don't bother. I assume you have a redist exe that you are distributing anyway, so just run that exe and it will do the right thing. The issue is that MS might ship a security fix package at any time and you cannot predict the key value or ProductCodes, plus you need to woyry about the architecture etc. Is there a reason you can't just run the redist and let it discover whether it needs to be installed or not?

Comment: "Just run that exe and it will do the right thing." I agree. In general, I'm not more knowledgeable about someone else's installer than the logic that they wrote. The only downside comes when the installer doesn't do the right thing or requires a very, very large optional download.

Comment: @PhilDW, Thanks for your answer and I am sorry for delaying to reply on the thread. I have already tried with the link as per you have suggested into Wix Toolset but could not get the success. Actually I made a Wix Bootstrapper project into Wix Toolset which installed my app MSI with VC++ 2008, VC++ 2010 redistributable as prerequisites installation.

Comment: @ Tom Blodget, Thanks for your answer and I am sorry for delaying to reply on the thread. Actually my need is as per I have suggested in my above thread.